# cross compiled core dump analysis

Tags: c++, arm, cross-compiling, embedded-linux, coredump

I have a arm cross compiled application which has generated a core dump. I want to use the core dump along with the corresponding source code to debug the issue. which tool can be used to analyze a specific core dump against the corresponding source code?

Comment: I'm looking for a method to do this: "gdb host_compiled_binary arm_generated_coredump_file"

Comment: Or let me put it this way: I have source code, and a core dump which was generated on a arm platform, how to analyze this coredump ?

Comment: there is gdb-multiarch in some distributions. i have not used it myself so just fyi